# How stable is the call stack, specifically -1?

Tags: r

Say I have some function, `f`:

```
f <- function() {
  print(sys.calls())
}
```

Say I have two additional functions,

```
g <- function() {
  f()
}
h <- function() {
  f()
}
```

Calling these functions result in:

```
> g()
[[1]]
g()

[[2]]
f()

> h()
[[1]]
h()

[[2]]
f()
```

Assuming that

1. None of the functions are further modified or overwritten,
2. The only places where `f` is ever called is inside `g` or `h`.

How reliable/stable/confident can I be that `f()` will always appear immediately after `g()` in the call stack, such that I can inside `f()` check `sys.call(-1)[[1]]` to determine whether `f` was called by `g` or `h`?

To put it another way, is there some use-pattern I'm missing where a user would do something that would insert another call in the stack between the call to `g` or `h`, and the call to `f`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call stack is stable in the sense that *directly* calling these functions will always result in the correct outer function being printed.

However, this does *not* mean that you can use this method to directly identify the outer function whenever `f()` is invoked. The problem comes when `g` or `h` are passed as arguments in functional programming contexts. These are very commonly used in R, even by end users.

For example, a caller could use `g` inside `do.call`

```r
do.call(g, list())
#> [[1]]
#> do.call(g, list())
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> (function() {
#>   f()
#> })()
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> f()
```

Note that there is not a stand-alone `g()` immediately before the call to `f()` because of the way that `g` has been invoked.

The same will be true if `g` or `h` are invoked inside one of the `*apply` family of functions, or `Map`, or `ave` or `Reduce`. And this is just in the base package, let alone extension packages.

Comment: Terrific, this is exactly the type of thing I was worried about. If I make the user-available functions wrappers around `g` and `h` it avoids the issue right? E.g. `g2 <- function() { g() }` then `do.call(g2, list())` works as expected.

Comment: @Josh yes, if `g` is unexported and is only ever called from `g2` then realistically you will be fine.